# Javascript Regex remove spaces around dash in numbers but not strings

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to remove spaces around dashes in a string, but only when within numbers:

`10 - 89 - 90` should become `10-89-90`.

But when within a string, they should keep the spaces:

`A - Z` should remain `A - Z`. As well as `90 - older` should stay `90 - older`.

So only when there are numbers on both sides of the dash, should the spaces be removed.

I tried this:

`item = item.replace(/(\d) - (\d)/g, "$1-$2");`

But nothing happened.

*Edit*: My dashes were indeed being turned into em dashes by Excel, but I accepted the answer since it does anticipate an issue I could very well run into (having only one digit in between dashes).

Comment: It is most probably because your spaces are hard/non-breaking spaces. Or your dash is not a hyphen, but some en/em-dash because [your code works](https://ideone.com/32at9C).

Comment: @tevemadar No need to. Actually, the second `\d` must be wrapped with a lookahead to allow overlapping number matching, as in The fourth bird's answer. The problem here is that we do not know what OP has as an input, either the spaces are not regular spaces, or hyphen/dash. `\s` solves the problem with whitespaces.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, yes, after all it's enough to match a single digit, out of many. But in fact then OP's original code works already with the example (replacing both ``` - ``` sequences), while the post says it doesn't. (found a bug in SO? I can't code format the dash with surrounding spaces)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `(\d) - (\d)` will work for `10 - 89 - 90` but it will not work for `10 - 8 - 9` as the single digit in the second `\d` is already matched.

There also must be at least a single space at the left and at the right of each digit, which would also not match the last space in `10 - 89 -90`

You can use

```
\b(\d+)\s*-\s*(?=\d+\b)
```

- `\b(\d+)` A word boundary, capture 1+ digits
- `\s*-\s*` Match a hyphen between optional whitespace chars
- `(?=\d+\b)` Positive lookahead, assert 1+ digits followed by a word boundary

And replace with

```
$1-
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BuiOEy/1)

```js
[
  "0 - 89 - 90",
  "90 - older"
].forEach(
  item => console.log(item.replace(/\b(\d+)\s*-\s*(?=\d)/g, "$1-"))
)
```

When the quantifier in the lookbehind is supported:

```js
[
  "0 - 89 - 90",
  "90 - older"
].forEach(
  item => console.log(item.replace(/(?<=\b\d+)\s*-\s*(?=\d+\b)/g, "-"))
)
```

Comment: Explanation? I assume you're in the process of editing to add one now, but in case you're not.

Comment: @Slbox It is comes in a a sec

Comment: Thanks a million. It may be a JavaScript issue, but I had to remove the `\b` word boundary for it to work.